# I can't add products to cart using safari

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

When I use safari, the products aren't added to cart. I dont see errors in the console or logs.

It works in localhost, but not in live server.

**EDIT:**

I realized that when I add the product the first time, it works, but if I remove it and try to add it again I can`t any more

Answer (score 0):

I think that this issue causes due to session cookie ! try to check and set this config :

1) `system->configuration->web->session`, cookie management section, set `cookie lifetime:0` `cookie path:{you put nothig}` `cookie domain:{you put nothig}` `Use Http only:yes` `cookie restriction mode:no`.

2) In server, check the right permissions of folders.

3) Clear your Magento and browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have set cookie domain `.yourdomain.com`

Increase your server memory. See the server memory in phpinfo() .

Clear your safari cache